# is not assignable to IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and trying to learn by coding. Here I have a component which has `isOrange = true`.

```
<InfoBox isOrange />
```

When I'm trying to access it would be like this: `function InfoBox({  isOrange }) {    return ( ...)}`, but it is giving me this error: `'Type '{ isOrange: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'isOrange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)'`, if I have understood it correctly I should have some kind of interface in order to get it to work ?
Sorry for any mistakes, english is not my native language.

Comment: Please provide full code of InfoBox, as well as where you use it

Comment: @hellogoodnight it wont let me use that 'isOrange', it is just there to mean 'true' when using it inside component i can use it as a 'true' in normal javascript react, but here it wont allow me

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @hellogoodnight if I don't put it equal to something, then it is automatically 'true'

Comment: @waleedd32 please provide full example. It may be automatically true for React, but not for TypeScript

Comment: @captain-yossarian basically it is like this : function InfoBox({
 
  isOrange ,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <Card
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={`infoBox  ${isOrange && "infoBox--orange"} `}
    >
     
      <CardContent>
        {" "}
        <Typography className="infoBox__title" color="textSecondary">
          {title}
        </Typography>{" "}
      </CardContent>{" "}
    </Card>
  );
}
,   when user cliks and it is already orange(true) then new className is infoBox--orange

Comment: Please share this code in typescript playground

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you trying to pass data to child component called InfoBox right?
if so, you have to add an interface on InfoBox component so it knows the coming data to it.

```
interface Props {
  isOrange:boolean;
}
```

and then pass Props to the function of the child component.

```
const childComponent:React.FC<Props> = ({isOrange}) => {
//here the code
}
```